# xSocket alternative to C library

Tags: java, c, sockets

Have a windows program writtent in C language. But need to sent message to the chat server.

I found xSocket which is written in Java, it would be great to have a simple C libraries that is able to sent message to xSocket server port like Port 8090.

Comment: Are you familiar with [Winsock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winsock)? It provides socket access and is part of Win32.

Comment: Nope, I need a simple code and cross-platform compatible for actionscript programmer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sockets programming using the Berkeley sockets library is so simple that it's probably best to just code something yourself. There are various C++ socket libraries, but they add little value to just writing a few simple functions yourself. There's loads of example code on the internet.

Key functions are:

socket() - creates a socket.
connect() - makes a connection.
send() - take a guess ;)
recv() - read data from socket.

If you just search something like "socket c example" on Google you should be fine.